# Weirdest android app crash

Tags: java, android

I've made a simple android quiz game for android 2.2 (sdk-8).
Everything works perfectly on my emulator, but when I try using the app on my smart phone (android 2.2) it crashes on the 9th question.

- 1-8 questions work perfectly on my smart phone (android 2.2)
- after 8th (on 9th) it crashes (smart phone)
- Everything works perfectly in my emulator, no crashes (Eclipse)
- I am %120 sure Im using .apk I exported from my android project in eclipse

Any idea what's wrong?

```
public class ETBetaActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button answer_1,
    answer_2,answer_3,
    answer_4,main;

    TextView q_textview,
    tip;

    private String a1,a2,a3,a4 = "";

    private int i1 = 0;
    public static int correct = 0;

    private boolean alive = true;

    MediaPlayer button_click;

    private String[] questions =
   {"Q1", 
    "Q2",
    "Q3", 
    "Q4",
    "Q5", //5
    "Q6", 
    "Q7", 
    "Q8", 
    "Q9", //CRASH!!!! WHAT THE FUDGE?!
    "Q10" //10
    };
    public static int question_amount = 10;
    private String[] answers_correct =
   {"Correct answer - 1",
    "Correct answer - 2",
    "Correct answer - 3", 
    "Correct answer - 4",
    "Correct answer - 5",
    "Correct answer - 6",
    "Correct answer - 7",
    "Correct answer - 8",
    "Correct answer - 9",
    "Correct answer - 10"
    };

    private String[][] answers_wrong = 
    { {"Q1-1", "Q1-2" , "Q1-3"},
      {"Q2-1", "Q2-2" , "Q2-3"},
      {"Q3-1", "Q3-2" , "Q3-3"},
      {"Q4-1", "Q4-2" , "Q4-3"},
      {"Q5-1", "Q5-2" , "Q5-3"},
      {"Q6-1", "Q6-2" , "Q6-3"},
      {"Q7-1", "Q7-2" , "Q7-3"},
      {"Q8-1", "Q8-2" , "Q8-3"},
      {"Q9-1", "Q9-2" , "Q9-3"},
      {"Q10-1", "Q10-2" , "Q10-3"}

    };


    List<String> question_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> answer_list_correct = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getData();
        Game(i1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (alive == false) {
        //  startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"));
            return;
        }
        button_click = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click);
        button_click.start();
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.button5: //main
            break;
        case R.id.button1: //answer_1
            if(isCorrect(1))
                correct++;


            break;
        case R.id.button2: //answer_2
            if(isCorrect(2))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button3: //answer_3
            if(isCorrect(3))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button4: //answer_3
            if(isCorrect(4))
                correct++;


            break;

        default:
            break;


        }
        Game(i1);
        //correct++;
        tip.setText("");
    }


    public static int getResults(){
        int value = (int) Math.floor((correct*5)/question_amount);
        if(value <= 0)
        return 1;
        else
        return value;
    }

    private boolean isCorrect(int button){
        for (int i = 0; i < answers_correct.length; i++){
        if(button == 1 && a1 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 2 && a2 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 3 && a3 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 4 && a4 == answers_correct[i])
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }

    private void Game(int q){
        if(i1 == question_amount) { //no more questions
            startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"));
            alive = false;
            return;
        }
        try {
        main.setText("Dunno");
    /*  String answer_list[][] = {
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]}
        }; */
        String answer_list[] = {
        answers_correct[q], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]     
        };

        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(answer_list));
        answer_1.setText(answer_list[0]);
        answer_2.setText(answer_list[1]);
        answer_3.setText(answer_list[2]);
        answer_4.setText(answer_list[3]);
        a1 = answer_list[0];
        a2 = answer_list[1];
        a3 = answer_list[2];
        a4 = answer_list[3];
        q_textview.setText(questions[q]);
        /*questions = question_list.toArray(new String[question_list.size()]);
        answers_correct = answer_list_correct.toArray(new String[answer_list_correct.size()]);
        question.setText(questions[i1]);        

        answer_list_correct.remove(questions[i1]);
        question_list.remove(questions[i1]);*/
        } catch (Exception ex){}
        i1++;
    }
    private void getData(){
        //Getting the data
        main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        answer_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        answer_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        answer_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        answer_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        q_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        tip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answ1);

        //Making the buttons, actually work
        main.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_3.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_4.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Resets the text
        //Note to self: Replace with another ContectView
        main.setText("Begin!");
        answer_4.setText("");
        answer_3.setText("");
        answer_2.setText("");
        answer_1.setText("");
        tip.setText("");

    /*  for(String x : questions) {
            for(String y : answers_correct){

            answer_list_correct.add(y);
            question_list.add(x);

            Collections.shuffle(answer_list_correct);
            Collections.shuffle(question_list);

            }
        } */



    }


    }
```

End intent/class

```
public class End extends Activity implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener {
   // ETBetaActivity classy = new ETBetaActivity();

    TextView score;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.end);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        results();
        final RatingBar yourRating = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        yourRating.setRating(ETBetaActivity.getResults());
        Toast.makeText(End.this, "Score "+ETBetaActivity.getResults(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         yourRating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
              boolean fromUser) {
              //  yourRating.setRating(rating);
                yourRating.setRating(ETBetaActivity.getResults());
                Toast.makeText(End.this, "Score "+ETBetaActivity.getResults(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});
     //movieImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);       
    }




    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void results(){
        score.setText("Your score  "+ETBetaActivity.getResults());
    }

    }
```

PS.
It's not 'END' class causing the error, cause I've tried

```
if(i1 == 4)
```

To call it earlier, and it worked perfectly.

Best regards.

Comment: This is all worthless without the log cat. Post the log of the phone.

Comment: How I do that? All I get is an error message saying process com.aleksti.etc was stopped.

Comment: Short guide: 1) Connect the phone via USB to your computer 2) Make sure that USB-Debugging is enabled *(`Settings -> Applications -> Development` on the phone)* 3) Show the logcat in eclipse via `Window -> Show View -> Other -> LogCat`. You should see a workspace window where all sorts of log messages are printed in different colors 4) Crash your app 5) Search for a big red part *(should look like [this](http://fullroom.com/_blog/LogCatStep3.png))* with the tag `AndroidRuntime`. 6) Post that here 7) Profit!

Comment: 1. Done, 2. Done, 3. Cant do that, cause it still runs the emulator. [2011-11-15 22:55:23 - ETBeta] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'DroidX'
[2011-11-15 22:55:23 - ETBeta] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'DroidX'
[2011-11-15 22:55:25 - ETBeta] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-11-15 22:55:25 - ETBeta] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

Comment: Activate debug mode on the phone. After that you'll be able to see the logcat in eclipse or ddms. If you don't know how to do it, I suggest you read the Android documentation/devguide on how to setup your development toolchain correctly.

Comment: Mhm open a command line window and run `adb devices` after step 2. You should see a list of the devices attached to your computer (emulators and real phones). If the phone is not visible you may have to install some USB drivers for it (depending on your operating system). You can find the `adb` command inside your `ANDROID_SDK/tools` directory. If you are not sure how to do that post your operating system and ill write a short guide. :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I need to get that USB driver first, thanks.

Comment: Ah, cant get the driver using SDK and AVD manager... Getting this error 'Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml, reason: File not found'

Comment: You might not certainly need the drivers from the sdk manager. These are for the google phones if i remember correctly (nexus series). Depending on which phone you have you should be able to get a driver from the manufacturers website *(e.g. download kies if you got a samsung phone or HTC sync if you have one from HTC - the drivers are packaged with these)*.

Comment: Ok i guess you can find it here: http://www.lg.com/us/support/mc-support/mobile-phone-support.jsp *(man LGs website su..s)*. Click Mobile Drivers on the top and select the one suitable for you.

Comment: It was the MediaPlayer. Also tyvm Alex, wouldn't fix it without you. Also why did I get '-1' :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that works on your emulator?
I tried it on 2.3.3 device and it crashes after 10th question when trying to run 
`startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"))`.
I changed it to `startActivity(new Intent(this, End.class))` and it works fine.

Btw, I had to remove lines with MediaPlayer initializing, as I don't have your music file

Comment: Nope, works fine with android 2.2 startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END")). Tried it my self aswell. (I just called it earlier on my phone, and it worked perfectly)

Comment: To call the End class using "com.aleksei.etb.END", you must declare it in the AndroidManifest.         </activity>
                <activity android:name=".End"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.aleksei.etb.END" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: @John Thank you, I didn't know this way, it works great now. That leaves three possibilities I guess - either some problems with 2.2 Android, something with MediaPlayer or corrupted exported apk. 
I would go with turning debug mode on phone, connecting it and seeing what shows up in LogCat or just debug using breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is an issue with `MediaPlayer.` It is actually never released and propably causes some memory issues. I also don't see the reason to create it every time it need to be used.

As for the other things IMO using some static fields to share values between Activities is not a good thing. Read about Intents, Extras and passing values to the Activity. I think you will find few examples on SO.

Comment: Yeah, just checked with LogCat, it was the MediaPlayer.

Comment: Ah, too late, Aleady fixed, but it was a null.

Comment: I think that someone gave you "-1" because you did not explain what was the real issue in here. It would be very nice to see the stack trace and find out something about the reason of a problem. And all we know now is that you had some problem with MediaPlayer... I also learn "to live" in this community and I also was downvoted yesterday(100% justified)  for not explaining my answer.